# Haskell error Main.hs:(39,1)-(44,64): Non-exhaustive patterns in function sumList

Tags: haskell

Can you help me with this issue?  The compiler generate this error:

```
Haskell error Main.hs:(39,1)-(44,64):
    Non-exhaustive patterns in function sumList
```

My code is

```
sumList:: [[Char]] -> [Char] -> Float
sumList [] element = 0
sumList (x:xs) element
     |x  == [] = 0
     |xs == [] = 0
     |x  == "" = 0
     |((splitOn "|" x)!!1) == element = 1 + (sumList xs element)
```

Comment: Why are you checking for x to be equal to both [] and ""? For a string, AFAIK, it's exactly the same. It would also be cleaner to write `null x || null xs` instead. You could probably also emit the parenthesis on the last line. Infix operators have a lower precedence then normal application. A float result also doesn't make much sense given its function (I'm actually surprised it compiled). You should also explain what you're trying to achieve; it's not obvious f of your code. You're trying to parse some text, and count the result?

Comment: Also for clarity's sake, your type signature should probably read `sumList :: [String] - > String -> Int`, (provided you don't actually need a float). If you post what your goal is, I'll try to make a fold (look up `foldr`).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it ,
need to add one more line to deal with the other situation
which is

```
|otherwise = (sumList xs element)
```

Answer (score 1):

I find your goal and code quite blur :

- Why the Float type ? Are you not trying to count something?
- Are `x  == [] = 0` and `x  == "" = 0` really both necessary ? How are they different?

I guessed that you wanted to count some elements, having some kind of tag. 
Tell me if I'm wrong.

I ended up with this code (not sure it corresponds to your problem) :

```
hasTag :: String -> String -> Bool
hasTag tag word = case splitOn "|" word of
                    _:[] -> False -- No tag
                    _:tags -> tag `elem` tags

countHavingTag :: String -> [String] -> Int 
countHavingTag tag = length . filter (hasTag tag)
```

Explicit recursion is quite un-idiomatic in Haskell, you usually don't need it.

You probably want to learn more about :

- types
- recursion (base case and recursion rules)
- partial function